# JTextArea - maintain clipboard functionality after setting TransferHandler

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtextarea

I'm following the example [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/339663/GUI/java/JTrees-Drag-Drop) to create a JTextArea that I can drop an object on and perform some action.  That works fine.  My problem is that after setting the TransferHandler with textArea.setTransferHandler(myTransferHandler), clipboard operations that work by default (cutting, copying, and pasting text) no longer work.

Is there a way to set a custom TransferHandler on my JTextArea to enable dragging objects but not interfere with the default clipboard functionality of JTextArea?  If not, what's the easiest way to modify the TransferHandler to allow regular clipboard operations to continue to function as normal?

Update:  here's an example that illustrates the problem.  I can drag-and-drop from the tree to the text area, but clipboard functionality on the text area is broken.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class DnDTest
{
    public DnDTest()
    {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeObject("root"));
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeObject("child1")));
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeObject("child2")));

        JTree tree = new JTree(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
        tree.setDragEnabled(true);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setDragEnabled(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        NodeObjectTransferHandler transferHandler = new NodeObjectTransferHandler();
        tree.setTransferHandler(transferHandler);
        textArea.setTransferHandler(transferHandler);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
        f.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        f.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
        f.setSize(500,400);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new DnDTest();
    }
}

class NodeObject {
    public String str;

    public NodeObject(String str) { this.str = str; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return str; }
}

class NodeObjectTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final DataFlavor nodeObjectFlavor = new DataFlavor(NodeObject.class, "NodeObject");

    @Override
    public boolean importData(JComponent c, Transferable t)
    {
        if (!canImport(c, t.getTransferDataFlavors())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(c instanceof JTextComponent)) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            NodeObject nodeObject = (NodeObject) t.getTransferData(nodeObjectFlavor);
            ((JTextComponent) c).setText(nodeObject.str);
            return true;
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c)
    {
        if (!(c instanceof JTree)) {
            return null;
        }

        JTree tree = (JTree) c;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode lastPathComponent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
        return new NodeObjectTransferable((NodeObject) lastPathComponent.getUserObject());
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
    {
        return COPY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(JComponent c, DataFlavor[] flavors)
    {
        for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
            if (flavor.match(nodeObjectFlavor)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class NodeObjectTransferable implements Transferable {
    private static final DataFlavor nodeObjectFlavor = new DataFlavor(NodeObject.class, "NodeObject");
    private NodeObject nodeObject;

    public NodeObjectTransferable(NodeObject nodeObject) {
        this.nodeObject = nodeObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
        if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }

        return nodeObject;
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
    {
        return new DataFlavor[] { nodeObjectFlavor };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
    {
        return flavor.match(nodeObjectFlavor);
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure if this suits your scenario. Instead of textArea.setTransferHandler() you can register textArea as DropTarget. And then handle all the import logic in DropTargetListener.drop() method. This way you don't interfere with TextTransferHandler used by JTextArea.

Comment: Thanks Max.  I wasn't aware of this functionality.  That sounds like it would make more sense for what I'm doing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Max hmm ... curious: how does it work out to have competing dnd handlers? Would expect lots of trouble because the dnd mechanism is a natural born singleton? So what I would do (and actually do) is to implement a delegating transferHandler. Which unfortunately is hampered by a design flaw of the TransferHandler (createTransferable is protected) which requires some c&p of the corresponding code from core ...

Comment: @kleopatra, I actually meant to have textArea's container as a DropTarget, my mistake in description.

Comment: Although @tenorsax 's answer sounds reasonable I'm still curious about how to solve the problem with a `TransferHandler`. In some old code I've used `TransferHandler`s successfully for drag'n'drop stuff--and back then copy & paste still worked well (older java versions I guess...?). Why isn't there a `DefaultIDontKnowTransferHandler` (so any other facilty) which I can use as default fallback for what my transfer handler is not able to handle?

Answer (score 0):

Same, I fix it by this way:

```
    area.getActionMap().put(TransferHandler.getCutAction().getValue(Action.NAME), TransferHandler.getCutAction());
    area.getActionMap().put(TransferHandler.getCopyAction().getValue(Action.NAME), TransferHandler.getCopyAction());
    area.getActionMap().put(TransferHandler.getPasteAction().getValue(Action.NAME), TransferHandler.getPasteAction());

    area.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {
        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return COPY_OR_MOVE;
        }

        @Override
        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
            return new StringSelection(area.getSelectedText());
        }

        @Override
        protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
            if (action == MOVE) area.replaceSelection("");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
            if (!canImport(support)) return false;
            try {
                if (support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    String data = (String) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                    area.replaceSelection(data);
                } else if (support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                    List<File> files = (List<File>) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                    if (!files.isEmpty()) {
                        area.setText(files.get(0).getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } catch (Exception ignored) {return false;}
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
            return support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) || (support.isDrop() && support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor));
        }

    });
```